# Simultaneous vs. one-by-one value assignment in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I am trying to rewrite simultaneous value assignment in a code to one-by-one value assignment, but I can't figure out how it works.

The original code is as follows (it reverses a linked list):

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def reverseList(self, head: ListNode) -> ListNode:
        rev=None
        while head:
            head.next,rev,head=rev,head,head.next
        return rev
```

I tried to rewrite the inside of while loop to

```
            tmp=head
            head.next=rev
            rev=tmp
            head=head.next
```

It doesn't work. When I input the linked list 1->2->3 it outputs 1, as opposed to 3->2->1.
I tried various other ways with no luck.

Could point out what I got wrong?
I would greatly appreciate your comment.
Thank you.

Comment: Please make a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Apart from the [mcve], also take the [tour] and read [ask] to help you ask better questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simultaneous assignment is a quick way of swapping and assigning values to variables without using something like `tmp`. For example,

```
a, b = b, a
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
```

In the example you provided, the solution uses this logic to assign new values to each variable:

```
head.next, rev, head = rev, head, head.next
```

If you want to use temporary variables to store intermediate values, you should do something like

```
tmp = head.next
head.next = rev
rev = head
head = tmp
```

Your code does not work as intended since `head` changes mid-way. `head.next = rev` will change the contents of `head.next`, which means that it will also affect the value of `tmp`, which stores `head`. Therefore, you should store `head.next` instead of `head` and assign `tmp` itself to `head` in the end.